# Apache HTTP Server 2.4 won't start on x64 Windows

Tags: apache-2.4

This is my first time installing Apache 2.4 and whenever I try to start it, the event log runs an error saying "The Apache HTTP Server service terminated with the following service-specific error: Incorrect function." I don't really know what to do next, so any tips will help!!

Comment: Could you please check the apache log and if that shows nothing the windows event log. There was a similar case mentioned here: https://superuser.com/questions/1105392/apache-2-4-with-openssl-service-failing-with-specific-error-incorrect-function

Answer (score 0):

In your description you said this is my first time,  Instead of using 'raw' Apache, I would recommend [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).  It is beginner friendly and it automatically sets up apache for you.  When I started doing these things, my friend showed me Xampp and it made things 10x easier.